# How are CSS files linked in wordpress to particular pages they belong to?

Tags: wordpress

I have read that the correct way to Load your style sheet in WordPress is to use  wp_enqueue_style in functions.php.

If i have different CSS for my index and home and other pages, how will the Server/WordPress know which style sheet is to be linked with a particular page and send to browser, or will it send all the CSS files to browser?

Comment: It will send them all, you can enqueue different styles to different pages using functions like `is_home()`, `is_archive()`, `is_single()` etc. Look them up on the WordPress codex.

Answer (score 1):

In your theme's **functions.php** file you can add code similar to this, please note that this example assumes the new CSS files live in the **css/** directory within your theme folder. If you don't have your folder structure like that, that's okay, just modify the path of the CSS file locations within the wp_enqueue_style() call.

```
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'change_page_styles' );
function change_page_styles() {

    // For the front page
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'front', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/front.css' );
    }

    // For the blog page
    if ( is_home() ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'blog', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/blog.css' );
    }

    // For regular pages
    if (is_page() && !is_front_page()) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'pages', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/pages.css' );  
    }
}
```

If you need other conditional tags to call out specific pages, post types, categories, etc. you can find the appropriate tag here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags